# How can i get data from mysql?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

I'm trying to make some data in my database editable by using "X-editable" Bootstrap plugin. What should my code look like? I need the anchor text to be pre-filled with data. This is what I have.

Html:

```
<a href="#" id="objekt_alias" value="selectbox-o" data-pk="1" data-url="include/objekt- redigera.php" data-type="text" data-placement="right" data-title="Alias"></a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//toggle `popup` / `inline` mode
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';     

//make username editable
$('#objekt_alias').editable();


    /*
    //uncomment these lines to send data on server
    ,pk: 1
    ,url: '/post'
    */
});
```

Comment: use ajax http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the jQuery website (linked by Arpit Srivastava below your post) and implement an ajax request like this :

```
function doAjaxRequest(id){
 $.ajax({
  url: "'/post'",
  data: { pk: id }, //complete this object to pass your data
 }).done(function() {
  alert('request done !');
 });
}
```